How to hide Google Ads that appeared on our printed documents?
We have a website on Blogger to print legal documents but when printing we got a Google Adsense message in the top of the page as you can see in the document picture and same message appears in the footer of the website and it's has this class .ipr-container and same with pop-up in bottom of the website that appears in the printed document and it has an ID #google-anno-sa and they are related to Google Ad intents and each document content exist inside this <div id="talabe-print">. I tried many CSS and Javascript solutions like this code to hide all classes and IDs but they don't work at all. However when I use developers tools and delete the DIVs related to .ipr-container and #google-anno-sa everything works fine. How can I hide those two elements to have a normal printed page with a CSS or JavaScript code.


@media print {
  .ipr-container, #google-anno-sa {
    display: none;
  }
}







Did you try placing the CSS rule in another file through the <link ... media='print' /> tag at the document root head? You can also try using the !important modifier...

I tried but it does not work at all. It seems that this auto Google ads are forcing themselves even on my code.



    <style>
    @media print {
        .ads, .ad { 
            display: none !important; 
        }
    }
</style>



Add this to your Head Tag , Here, .ads and .ad are common classes used for ads. You can adjust the class names based on what your theme uses.

Thanks for your answer but it seems that Google inject this text message because of auto ads this is my full code .adsbygoogle.adsbygoogle-noablate,.adsbygoogle,.google-ads,.google-photos-ads,.google-photos-ads2,.google-photo-ad,#google-posts-ads,.google-auto-placed,#gda,.google-anno-sa-qtx,.google-anno-skip,.adsbygoogle_adsbygoogle-noablate,.adsbygoogle-noablate,.google-anno-sa,#google_ads_iframe,[id^="aswift_"],iframe[src*="google"],.ad-container,.google-auto-placed,.ad-slot,.adsense-ad,#page2print,.ft-reg-bubble,#ipr-container,[class*="ad-"],[class*="google-"]{display:none!important}

try to provide a print button like the below code: Print this page

I have a button to print the document as you can see https://www.talabe.ma/2021/01/modele-procuration-maroc-pdf-doc-word.html
